# Moving to another view without NavigationView

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have NavigationView in ContentView

```
struct ContentView: View {

var body: some View {
    
    
    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            
            BarView()
            AdsView()
            SelectTypeVideo()
            
            Spacer()
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea(.all)
    }
  }
}
```

I can't use it either in a sub-struct like BarView()

I tried to use the first

```
if isSearch {
        SearchBar()
    }
```

or

```
.onTapGesture {
          isSearch.toggle()
     }
```

Doesn't respond when pressed

I want to move from the BarView() to the SearchBar()

```
struct BarView: View {

@State var isSearch = false
var body: some View {
    
    if isSearch {
        SearchBar()
    }
        HStack {
            
            ZStack {
                HStack {
                    
                    Button(action: { isSearch.toggle() }) {
                        
                        ZStack {
                            Rectangle()
                                .fill(Color.white)
                                .cornerRadius(10)
                                .shadow(color: .black.opacity(0.2), radius: 10)
                                .frame(maxWidth: 35, maxHeight: 35)
                                .padding(.top, 25)
                            Image(systemName: "gear")
                                .padding(.top, 25).padding()
                                .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                                
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Spacer()
            Text("other")
                .padding(.top, 30).padding()
                .font(.title)
            
            
        }.padding(.top, 10)
    }
}
```

Sorry if the question is simple, but I didn't find a solution

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You definitely need a simpler, but more complete example. Also, what, exactly, is the problem vs. what do you expect?

Comment: I mentioned it in the topic. I want to move from one view to another without the navigationview Because I used it before on the main view

Comment: Are these views in the navigation hierarchy? If so, then you are using a `NavigationView` as it flows down the hierarchy. The next question is how do you want to navigate? There are many different options. I would recommend you study [Apple’s SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui) & [Stanford’s CS193P](https://cs193p.sites.stanford.edu/).

Comment: In your question you say you want to move from one view to another but do not specify from which view to which other one. You can use sheet for example.

Comment: I just want to switch from **BarView()** to **SearchBar()** Without transferring any data, only transfer

Comment: without using **NavigationView** Because I used it in the main view

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
if isSearch {
    SearchBar()
}
```

from **BarView** and place it in ContentView like this

```
if isSearch {
    SearchBar()
} else {
    BarView()
}
```

Comment: Nothing changes

Comment: can you show me where did you make change

Comment: I found out the reason is because the **BarView()** place on the screen is in the Navigation place at the top of the screen

Comment: Because I use the NavigationView in the main view

Comment: When I put it in the middle of the screen, it responds to me when I press the button